# UIButton image/backgroundimage scaling issues

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have tried everything, so I finally decided to post this question. I have a button (well, quite a few actually) that holds an image, which was working fine, until my employer decided they were too small. First thing I did was get some new pictures, that were bigger, so the resolution wouldn't be bad. Now when I tried to "oversize" my button, at some point the image just didn't want to follow anymore and stopped scaling. I went searching on the internet, and saw that everybody was telling ppl to put their image as background image instead. I did that, but then a new problem raised: resolution was awful. So basically I have two question.
1. Is it really not possible to make a buttons image scaletofill; do you really have to work around by using background image.
2. Is there any reason that somebody else can think of why my resolution would be bad, as the picture I use is actually *bigger than the background* (and the proportions are correct). I originally had smaller pictures, but I deleted them from images assets and loaded in the new ones. I can't imagine Xcode somehow retaining a snapshot of the old pictures, but this makes no sense to me.

[image: Button with both an image and background image. bgimg being blurry. image not sizing out]

Any clearance on the subject greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove app from simulator or device and clean Xcode build cache (Build->Clean)

Comment: That damn worked, thank you very much! Seems odd though as I have switched around pictures like that before. I still wonder what all the fuss is about having to use background images to make it scale. I saw that in so may posts I've read through

Comment: Sometimes this actions will helps in other "strange" issues of Xcode